# Selection of rows and child rows in data tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am working on a data table with child rows (marked by red color) where only a single (main) row can be selected by clicking (marked by blue color).

[image: Data table with folded child]

1. I want the main row to stay selected when the child row is unfolded (red minus sign) or folded (green plus sign) again. However, I can not get it to work as shown below.

[image: Data table with unfolded child]

2. Additionally, is there a way to prevent the child rows from being selectable?

[image: Data table with selected child]

Here is the Javascript function that I have implemented so far. Could someone please help me with these problems? Thank you very much in advance!

```
// Text format of the displayed text in the child row
var format = function( d ) {  //
   return '<div class=\"child-row-abstract\"> ' + d[5] + '</div>';
};

// Column with index=0 is selectable per mouse
table.column(0).nodes().to$().css({cursor: 'pointer'});

// Open/close child row
table.on('click', 'td.details-control', function() {
   var td = $(this);
   var row = table.row(td.closest('tr'));
   if (!row.child.isShown()) {
      row.child(format(row.data())).show();
      td.html(", quote(symbol_minus), ");
   } else {
      row.child.hide();
      td.html(", quote(symbol_plus), ");
   }
});
```

Comment: We need a complete snippet for help you, please create it with tool `[<>]`

Comment: Does your code do anything, as-is? Is it throwing an error? We'll need to see the html too to help figure out what's going on.

Comment: Actually, the posted code is part of a shiny program which is too big to post it here. I am going to break it down to a runable example and then repost it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you are targeting a Shiny app for this, but here is a vanilla DataTables approach, which you should be able to adapt to Shiny.

1. Prevent the row selection/deselection from working when the user clicks on the first column - the one containing the open/close buttons.
2. For the first column, enable row selection inside the open/close event listener code.
3. Ensure you have configured the select style to be `'single'`.

---

**Step 1:**

This allows you to separate the open/close functionality from the select/deselect functionality:

```js
table.on( 'user-select', function ( e, dt, type, cell, originalEvent ) {
  if ( $(originalEvent.target).index() === 0 ) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
} );
```

[Reference](https://datatables.net/extensions/select/examples/api/cancellableEvents.html).

---

**Step 2:**

Add `row.select();` to the end of the open/close event listener code.

[Reference](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().select()).

---

**Step 3:**

Use the single-row selection style.

```
select: {
  style: 'single'
}
```

[Reference](https://datatables.net/reference/option/select.style).

---

**Basic demo:**

Note: the demo does not have the icons for `+` (open) and `-` (close) - so you have to imagine those, and just click on the empty cells in the first column.

```js
var dataSet = [{
    "id": "123",
    "name": "Tiger Nixon",
    "position": "System Architect",
    "salary": "$320,800",
    "start_date": "2011/04/25",
    "office": "Edinburgh",
    "extn": "5421"
  },
  {
    "id": "456",
    "name": "Donna Snider",
    "position": "Customer Support",
    "salary": "$112,000",
    "start_date": "2011/01/25",
    "office": "New York",
    "extn": "4226"
  },
  {
    "id": "567",
    "name": "Cedric Kelly",
    "position": "Senior Javascript Developer",
    "salary": "$433,060",
    "start_date": "2012/03/29",
    "office": "Edinburgh",
    "extn": "6224"
  },
  {
    "id": "432",
    "name": "Airi Satou",
    "position": "Accountant",
    "salary": "$162,700",
    "start_date": "2008/11/28",
    "office": "Tokyo",
    "extn": "5407"
  },
  {
    "id": "987",
    "name": "Brielle Williamson",
    "position": "Integration Specialist",
    "salary": "$372,000",
    "start_date": "2012/12/02",
    "office": "New York",
    "extn": "4804"
  }
];

/* Formatting function for row details - modify as you need */
function format(d) {
  // `d` is the original data object for the row
  return '<table class="cell-border" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">' +
    '<tr>' +
    '<td>Full name:</td>' +
    '<td>' + d.name + '</td>' +
    '</tr>' +
    '<tr>' +
    '<td>Extension number:</td>' +
    '<td>' + d.extn + '</td>' +
    '</tr>' +
    '<tr>' +
    '<td>Extra info:</td>' +
    '<td>And any further details here (images etc)...</td>' +
    '</tr>' +
    '</table>';
}

$(document).ready(function() {

  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    select: {
      style: 'single'
    },
    data: dataSet,
    "columns": [{
        "className": 'details-control',
        "orderable": false,
        "data": null,
        "defaultContent": ''
      },
      {
        "data": "name"
      },
      {
        "data": "position"
      },
      {
        "data": "office"
      },
      {
        "data": "salary"
      }
    ],
    "order": [
      [1, 'asc']
    ]
  });



  // Add event listener for opening and closing details
  $('#example tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function() {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var row = table.row(tr);

    if (row.child.isShown()) {
      // This row is already open - close it
      row.child.hide();
      tr.removeClass('shown');
    } else {
      // Open this row
      row.child(format(row.data())).show();
      tr.addClass('shown');
    }
    row.select();
  });


  table
    .on('user-select', function(e, dt, type, cell, originalEvent) {
      if ($(originalEvent.target).index() === 0) {
        e.preventDefault();
      }
    });




});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Demo</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/jquery.dataTables.css">

  <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.6.2/css/select.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.6.2/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://datatables.net/media/css/site-examples.css">

  <style>
    td.details-control {
      background: url('./resources/details_open.png') no-repeat center center;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    tr.shown td.details-control {
      background: url('./resources/details_close.png') no-repeat center center;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>

  <div style="margin: 20px;">

    <table id="example" class="display dataTable cell-border" style="width:100%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Position</th>
          <th>Office</th>
          <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Position</th>
          <th>Office</th>
          <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>

  </div>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Additionally, make sure that you have included the extension package _"Select"_, e.g., 
`DT::datatable(data = df, selection = "none", extensions = c("Buttons", "Select"), options = list(select = list(style = "single", items = "row")), callback = DT::JS(" ... "))' 
Thank you very much again!